# select2 tags support, how to prohibit option to be a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I use select2 with ajax search.How to set some option couldn't be selected.
for example,like the image below
[image]

I wrote a 'w' in the input, but the first line in the drop down is not the data come from ajax search. how to set it couldn't be selected or don't show it?

html code

```
<select id="normalSymptom" name="normalSymptom" class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple > </select>
```

javascript code

```
$('#normalSymptom').select2({
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 10,
    ajax: {
        url: "/DiseaseSearch/symptomSearch",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: function (params) {
            var queryParameters = {
                word: params.term
            }
            return queryParameters;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.name,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Please provide your js code

Comment: thank you , here is the code

Comment: Does this **white** tag come from ajax ?

Comment: yes ```white``` tag come form ajax. but ```w``` is what I input

Comment: So any tag that starts with ***w*** should not be selected. Right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you are allowed to create new tags.

To disable tag creation, supply a `createTag` option. This option is a function that indicates whether a given tag is allowable. In your case, you want to allow *no* tags to be created, so return null, e.g.,

```
$('#normalSymptom').select2({
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  createTag: function (params) {
    return null;
  },
  // etc.
});
```

[See JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/gy3trd35/)

Answer (score 0):

I've not played around using select2 for a while, but i believe that is the intended behavior of the plugin.
This being said, You should be able to find the id/class of the element that has the 'w' in and set it to `display: none;`, this has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('select').select2({tags:false});
```

Comment: That's only an option if they don't want tags, which it looks like they do, based on setting tags to true :/

Comment: Oh , actually, I need ```tags:ture```, but I just don't want the first line that I input show up

Answer (score 0):

Remove "multiple" from your html

```
<select multiple></select>
```

Actually whenever we write multiple in select it become tags to select more than 1 option. When you remove it, it become like single select option. I Hope it is helpful! :)